# Can´t connect VM to the Internet

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I´m just setting up my Mac VM and it can´t connect to the internet. [image: This is my Bridge setting]
Since it´s my first VM I have no idea what I´m doing wrong, cause I did everything like the tutorial :/
I hope somebody can help me :)

I tried every bridge, I read an article that I have to do something in the settings from windows, but I couldn´t find it.

Comment: It helps to list the action you took when try to connect to internet. Eg. ping output. Browser error(if not headless).